# an optimal select function for vector extensions?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, clang, simd

OpenCL has a `select` [function](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/select.html), that is usable with all-vector arguments. Both clang and gcc support vector types as well, but only gcc currently supports a ternary operator supporting vectors and none of them has an OpenCL-like `select` function yet. I've tried to implement a replacement, but the results are non-optimal, with both gcc and clang producing conditional jumps. However, gcc does a pretty good job with its ternary operator, so it serves very well as a drop-in replacement. Does an optimal solution for a `select`-like function exist (particularly under clang) and what is it? Here are some non-optimal ideas:

```
template <typename U, typename V>
inline V select(U const s, V const a, V const b) noexcept
{
// a for loop gives horrible results
/*
  constexpr U zero{}; // for clang only

  return (-(s != zero) * a) - ((s == zero) * b);
*/
  return V{
    s[0] ? a[0] : b[0],
    s[1] ? a[1] : b[1],
    s[2] ? a[2] : b[2],
    s[3] ? a[3] : b[3]
  }; // for 4-component vectors only, one could generalize with the indices trick
/*
  return s ? a : b; // for gcc
*/
}
```

Comment: you could write a template to generate the unrolled loop for n-ary vectors

Comment: @Manu343726 Yeah, I know, but I didn't want to complicate my question, so I unrolled by hand for a 4-component vector. Some conditional jumps are still generated.

Comment: Accepting argument by `const` *reference* would be wise.  You say clang's ternary operator's producing bad code but 1) don't illustrate how you think it's inefficient or what's better (as the asm level), and 2) don't list the clang version / command-line flags...?  What `for` loop code did you have that produced bad output?

Comment: @TonyD 1) clang does not provide a ternary operator for vector types at all, but gcc does, I accept by value to encourage passing in a register . 2) -O3 clang-3.4.2 3) `V result; for(unsigned i{}; i != 4; ++i) result[i] = s[i] ? a[i] : b[i]; return result;` It is not unrolled at all. Bad code is basically conditional branches. These rarely happen (never seen them) with gcc's ternary operator.

Comment: 1) it's got nothing to do with ternary operators supporting `vector`s... your code extracts a reference to the vector elements before the ternary operator kicks in, 3) that has undefined behaviour - indexing off the end - you might try `V result(4);` to immediately allocate the necessary size.  GCC's `?` often generates conditional branches (not a lot of options really - what do you expect it to do instead?)... can you post the assembly for GCC `-S` that you say's not conditionally branching?

Comment: @TonyD These are simd vectors I am referring to. Look at my sample answer to my question (which I won't accept), to see what I have in mind.

Comment: @user1095108 wish you'd made it clearer you were talking about non-Standard vectors and specifically `int` elements, but then maybe I should have clicked on your OpenCL link.  Anyway, you say " still not as good, as something an optimizer would produce" - so - what *does* the optimiser produce?  It helps to know where you're trying to get to....

Comment: @TonyD The optimizer is almost magical. If I, say, write `a > b ? a : b`, the optimizer might generate a `maxps` instruction, foregoing the ANDing and ORing. Thus, by using my `select()` function, I also lose these nice optimization touches.

Comment: You'll probably need inline assembly or an intrinsic.  If you search for Intel Intrinsics Guide and their GCC headers, that may help.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles to semi-good code under both gcc and clang:

```
template <typename U, typename V>
constexpr inline V select(U const s, V const a, V const b) noexcept
{      
  return V((s & U(a)) | (~s & U(b)));
}
```

asm listing:

```
Dump of assembler code for function select<int __vector(4), float __vector(4)>(int __vector(4), float __vector(4), float __vector(4)):
   0x00000000004009c0 <+0>:     andps  %xmm0,%xmm1
   0x00000000004009c3 <+3>:     andnps %xmm2,%xmm0
   0x00000000004009c6 <+6>:     orps   %xmm1,%xmm0
   0x00000000004009c9 <+9>:     retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

This is still not as good, as something an optimizer would produce. The way it works is by abusing the vector casts and the fact, that comparison operations produce -1 (all ones) integers in places where the comparison matches. At least there are no arithmetic operations necessary.